Problem 1 on page 2 of Avner Friedman's PDE book.
First some notation.
$|\alpha|=\alpha_1+\ldots +\alpha_n$, $x=(x_1,\ldots,x_n)$, $D_i=\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}$, $D^\alpha=D_1^{\alpha_1}\ldots D_n^{\alpha_n}$.
A linear partial differential operator is an expression of the form:
$$(1.1)\ \ \ \sum_{|\alpha|\le m} a_\alpha(x)D^\alpha\equiv \sum_{k=0}^m \sum_{\alpha_1+\ldots \alpha_n=k}a_{\alpha_1\ldots +\alpha_n}(x)D_1^{\alpha_1}\ldots D_n^{\alpha_n}$$
The operator above in (1.1) is said to be elliptic at a point $x^{\alpha}=x^{\alpha_1}\ldots x^{\alpha_n}\in \Omega$ if $\sum_{|\alpha|=m}a_{\alpha}(x^0)\xi^{\alpha}\ne 0$ for any real $\xi\ne 0$.
It's called strongly elliptic iff:
$$(-1)^p\Re\{ \sum_{|\alpha|=2p}a_{\alpha}(x^0)\xi^\alpha\}>0 \ \ \ \forall 0\ne\xi\in \mathbb{R}$$
where $p\in\mathbb{N}$.
The problem ask to prove the following:
(1)Substitute in (1.1) $y=f(x)$ where $f\in C^m$ with nonvanishing Jacobian $(\partial f /\partial x)$. Prove that the new operator $\sum b_\beta D^\beta $ $(D_i=\partial/\partial y_i$ is elliptic (strongly elliptic) iff the same is true of the operator (1.1).
Is it just a change of variables, i.e. instead of x in (1.1) I plug and chug f(x) instead of $x$, or I should assume that $f$ has an inverse function, and plug $x=f^{-1}(y)$ instead of $x$ in Eq. (1.1), what do you think?
Thanks in advance!

(1.1) is very strange! on the left of equality is finite order, on the right of the equality is infinite order

@monotoneoperator indeed, you are correct it should be $m$ instead of $\infty$. Typo.

@MathematicalPhysicist I am wondering, you can tell me if I am wrong so I can delete my comment, but if you are on page 2, then it seems you are trying to learn PDEs? Your name suggests you are also interested in physics. Be careful, some books on PDEs are much more theory based, and do not help much for physics. Walter Strauss has a much better book suitable for people with an interest in physics. I am just bringing it up before you start Friedman. If you already know all of this, and this information is not helpful, you can let me know to delete my comment.

@NicolasBourbaki I know some PDE theory (had taken 3 courses on PDE and two courses on ODE). But one can't know enough of PDE. As you might tell I am not interested only on physics.

Let me have a try, according $y=f(x)$ and $f$ has nonvanishing jacobian $\partial f/\partial x$, so we have inverse function, WLOG, we denote it by $x=g(y)$.
Let us see the simplest situation $m=2,n=1$, we know that $$\frac{\partial^{2}}{\partial x^{2}}=(\frac{\partial f}{\partial x})^{2}\frac{\partial^2}{\partial y^{2}}+\frac{\partial^{2}f}{\partial x^{2}}\frac{\partial}{\partial y}$$
so the principle part $$(\frac{\partial f}{\partial x})^{2}\frac{\partial^2}{\partial y^{2}}$$ is strictly elliptic.
For more complex situation, after change of variable, the principle symbol is $$a_{\alpha}\big(g(y)\big)\Big(\frac{\partial y_{j_1}}{\partial x_{1}}\eta_{j_1}\Big)^{\alpha_{1}}\Big(\frac{\partial y_{j_2}}{\partial x_{2}}\eta_{j_2}\Big)^{\alpha_{2}}\dots\Big(\frac{\partial y_{j_1}}{\partial x_{n}}\eta_{j_n}\Big)^{\alpha_{n}}=a_{\alpha}(g(y))\bigg((\frac{\partial y}{\partial x})^{tr}\eta\bigg)^{\alpha}$$
in the above, we use Einstein summation convention and your notation about $x^{\alpha}=\dots$. If at $x_{0}$, the original operator is (strongly)elliptic, then after the change of variable and the jacobian is invertible, the operator(after change, the coefficient is depend on $y$) is also (strongly)elliptic. So, we can get the final conclusion.

that's what was missing in my reasoning the fact that the Jacobian is nonvanishing means the inverse exists and we can change backwards to $f^{-1}(y)=x$, am I right? Thanks. (and then there's the derivative of inverse function formula which I had long forgotten, but can search for.)

Yes, you are right, but just knowing Jacobian is invertible is enough! As for the formula of derivative of inverse function, I think in this situation, we don't need
